# Converting a File with Strings into Floats then Adding Them

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I have to create a program for my class that reads a file, coverts the lists of numbers within to floats, then adds them all together and prints only the answer onto the screen.

The farthest I've gotten is:

```
fname = sys.argv[1]
handle = open(fname, "r")
total = 0
for line in handle:
     linearr = line.split()
     for item in linearr:
          item = float(item)
```

One of the files look like:

```
0.13    10.2    15.8193
0.09    99.6
100.1
100.2   17.8    56.33    12
19e-2   7.5
```

Trying to add the converted list to the total (total += item) has not worked. I'm really lost and would greatly appreciate any assistance.

Comment: What's doen't work? Where do you adding the item to total?

Comment: You can make it shorter with list comprehension: `total = sum(float(item) for line in handle for item in line.split())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. `total += item` is the correct approach, add that line to your `for` loop after the conversion to float.

Make sure to print your result at the end with `print(total)`, you probably forgot that too.

For your test file this is giving me the result 419.9593

Comment: Thanks! I'm confused as I've put that before and I got errors... Must have made a mistake somewhere in an earlier attempt. Now my question is how to get it to print only the result.

Comment: @Alfador01 we can't help you if you don't give us the exact error message. I already told you how to only print the result. Add the line `print(total)` at the end of your program (not in the loop!).

Comment: Figured out my issue! I had put it at the end of the for loop. I moved it out and now I'm getting what I need! I feel dumb.. Thanks!

Comment: @Alfador01 no problem. As I said, next time when getting an error please post the full error message in the question. You will get faster and better answers if we don't have to ask follow up questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a *generator expression* with [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#sum),splitting the lines into lists and casting each subelement to float:

```
In [9]: cat test.txt
0.13    10.2    15.8193
0.09    99.6
100.1
100.2   17.8    56.33    12
19e-2   7.5

In [10]: with open("test.txt") as f:
            sm = sum(float(s) for row in map(str.split, f) for s in row)
   ....:     

In [11]: sm
Out[11]: 419.9593
```

You can also combine with [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to flatten the rows:

```
In [1]: from itertools import  chain

In [2]: with open("test.txt") as f:
            sm = sum(map(float, chain(*(map(str.split,f)))))
   ...:     

In [3]: sm
Out[3]: 419.9593
```

On a sidenote, you should always use [`with`](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) to open your files, it will automatically close your files for you.